# How do you customize standard dialog text in WiX?

Tags: wix, customization

I'm having some trouble getting WiX 3.6beta2 to behave the way I think it's supposed to.  I'm running light thusly:

```
light -loc strings.wxl
```

where strings.wxl has the line

```
<String Id="InstallDirDlgDescription>Click Next to install.</String>
```

I expect that to change the text in the "Destination Folder" under the title to my text, but it is not.  According to the documentation, adding the line

```
<String Id="WelcomeDlgDescription">This is a custom welcome message. Click Next to continue or Cancel to exit.</String>
```

to strings.wxl should change the descriptive text on the welcome dialog, but I'm not seeing that either.  What am I missing?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that it's extremely helpful to point to the *correct* .wxl file if you actually want WiX to use the localized values. PEBKAC. :P